# Daemon Thread prevents JVM from terminating - possible reasons?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I need to develop a maven plugin that can start an apache ftp-server, run it as a daemon (does not halt the build process) and stop it as another goal. Unfortunately my first attempt to with daemon threads fails:

```
public class FtpServerDaemon
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override public void run()
                    {
                        org.apache.ftpserver.main.Daemon.main(args);
                    }
                });

        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

The bad thing here is that the JVM does not terminate after 10 seconds but it runs indefinitely. If the `Daemon.main` is a black-box code (however the source is [available](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=mina-ftpserver.git;a=blob;f=core/src/main/java/org/apache/ftpserver/main/Daemon.java)), what can prevent the JVM from terminating in a daemon thread?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd suspect that the FTP server is firing off its own threads.

Comment: You can take a thread dump to see what non-daemon threads are live - probably one spawned by `server.start()` in the code of `Daemon.main`...

Comment: A daemon thread doesn't prevent a shutdown by definition, you have a thread which is a non-daemon which is still running.  Try `jstack {pid}` to see which threads are still running

Comment: Thank you guys, the answer is that a daemon can spawn non-daemon threads and that is what the FtpServer does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FtpServer starts non-daemon threads and they are still running. If a thread is spawned from a daemon thread, the new thread will initially inherit the daemon status from its parent, but one can override it. E.g.:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override public void run()
                    {

                        Thread embeddedNonDaemon = new Thread(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override public void run()
                                    {
                                        while (true)
                                        {
                                            ;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                        embeddedNonDaemon.setDaemon(false);
                        embeddedNonDaemon.start();
                    }
                });

        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

This code does not terminate, either.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with assylias and chrylis comments.

Instead of `org.apache.ftpserver.main.Daemon.main(args);` can you try some other code there? A loop that lasts more than the time the main thread sleeps should do, printing a number every n seconds or something.

I believe it must then terminate properly. Just to test whether the ftpserver is preventing the exit.

By the way, if a Daemon thread spawns a child thread, the child threads are automatically set as Daemon, right? So why this might be happening?

Comment: Yes, if I try while(true); instead of Daemon.main(args), it works as expected: JVM is terminated after 10 sec.

Comment: @toni77 Underneath, default implementation launches a ThreadPoolExecutor which are non-daemon threads.